# Changing image gallery by button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

First things first, I'm building my website on Bootstrap 3, which has it's own image gallery element in it. What I basically want to achieve, is that when I have a couple of **buttons** and the **gallery element** **on the same page**, pressing some of the **buttons changes the images in the gallery element**.

Tried to Google it but couldn't find any solutions that would satisfy my needs. Here are a couple of screenshots. JSFiddle is a bit difficult thing to be offered here, since I can't really include the image gallery element from Bootstrap, and including just the buttons would be a waste.

**This is what I got right now:**
[image]

**This requires** some sort of a knowledge about Bootstrap and JS/jQuery, since I'm not able to provide any demo-site or fiddle for this. All working solutions deserve my thanks!

**UPDATE:**

Here is the source code for the image-gallery, what it looks like in the firebug inspector. This should be of use for someone, since this still goes unsolved.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for this: http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look at it and see if I figure it out on how to apply that to an image gallery element, since I can't reach the element's code itself.

Comment: This really did it, not directly, got to hazzle a bit with jQuery, but got it working, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this markup for your gallery. You need to wrap the images, that each button should show in one div container

```
<a href="#" id="btn1" class="btn" >Button 1</a>
<a href="#" id="btn2" class="btn" >Button 2</a>
<a href="#" id="btn3" class="btn" >Button 3</a>
<div class="gallery">
<div id="cat1" class="cat">
  <img src="//placehold.it/50x50">
  <img src="//placehold.it/50x50">
  <img src="//placehold.it/50x50">
</div>  
  <div id="cat2" class="cat" style="display:none;">
    <img src="//placehold.it/50x50/ffff00">
  <img src="//placehold.it/50x50/ffff00">
  <img src="//placehold.it/50x50/ffff00">
</div> 
  <div id="cat3" class="cat" style="display:none;">
  <img src="//placehold.it/50x50/00ff00">
    <img src="//placehold.it/50x50/00ff00">
    <img src="//placehold.it/50x50/00ff00">
</div> 
</div>
```

And add this Jquery code to the end of the page

```
function show(id)
{

$('.cat').hide();
 $('#cat'+id).css('display','block');  
}

$('#btn1').click(function(){show('1')});
$('#btn2').click(function(){show('2')});
$('#btn3').click(function(){show('3')});
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm able to use this directly as it is. In my case, there are separate galleries (folders in file manager), I think I might be able to use them. I'll keep you tuned of the progress!

Comment: How do you generate this gallery

Comment: It is a default plugin for the portal platform I'm using. The biggest problem here is that it's not open-source, so I can't really affect to stuff that much or give you further information about it.